# rename attributes in Cloudera SQL

Tags: sql, cloudera-cdh

how can I rename the attributes of a variable within a create statement in Cloudera?

```
CREATE TABLE new
STORED AS PARQUET AS
SELECT DISTINCT
customer_number,
created_at,
service
From old;
```

Whereby I want to rename in the variable 'service' : 
Call me  = phone
Email me = email

Answer (score 0):

You would use `case`:

```
CREATE TABLE new STORED AS PARQUET AS
    select distinct customer_number, created_at,
           (case when service = 'Call me' then 'phone'
                 when service = 'Email me' then 'email'
                 else service
            end) as service
    from old;
```